# WIndows Terminal SSH Connection Logging

Tags: windows, ssh, connection, logging, windows-terminal

I have been advised to assess the usage of Windows Terminal in our environment which spans across four domains. As it is possible to use SSH to connect to different servers using Windows Terminal, our IT Sec team want to know if it is possible to log the connections with the username for accountability. I understand that PuTTy is capable of logging a full SSH session, but could PuTTy also be used to log an SSH session for Windows Terminal or is there another, ideally easier, method of doing it?

Comment: Is "usage" from your question just login? What about the Windows security log is that an option?

Comment: If the security logs have a specific event ID for ssh connections then that might work. I suppose configuring an xml to search the event log could filter the results.

The usage is more about using Windows Terminal to run commands on servers without having to rdp on to the server itself. Our IT Sec team just want the connections loggrd for accountability purposes